# Just updated Xubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 and cannot boot

Tags: boot, xubuntu, acer

I recently updated Xubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 and whenever i boot i get this message:`/dev/sda1: clean, 219723/7266304 files, 1918378/29046016`. I have a Acer Aspire One ZG5 that had Windows 10 Professional installed before Xubuntu. I installed Xubuntu about a month ago and just got the update. I have been waiting about an hour and several restarts, but nothing worked.

Comment: fyi: that message is only a `fsck` (file system check report) showing no errors and means little.   If you have grub appearing (and not selecting OS via eUFI) i would suggest hitting <E> (instead of enter on Ubuntu prompt; <E> is for edit) then going down to the `linux` line and removing keywords 'quiet splash' (so it doesn't hide hide boot messages and hide show graphics) and maybe adding '1' (single user recovery mode) so you can login to terminal & explore why.  Depending on hardware you could try adding `nomodeset' to the linux line...

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the ISO for Ubuntu 17.10 to a USB stick and go from there. I have had better results with a fresh install of the OS instead of OS updates. Here is the link:
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Won't that delete my data i had on my previous installation?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Did you backup your data at all? If not, backup the data you want and proceed installing the fresh OS.

Comment: How can I backup my data if my computer does not even boot? Is there a way to back up my data through the terminal?

Comment: I have not backed up my data via terminal personally to be honest with you. Try and take a look at this for help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuou5OiNnvA